# Having a different radius for different indicies/queries using a radius filter query

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

Current Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1a178bc4118f850d9cd

The flaw here is that I have two indicies in the searchable alias. This means that I must use the same radius for both. I actually want to use a larger radius in the radius filter for one of the indicies. Is there any way to do this without having two separate calls to .prepareSearch, thus two separate hits to Elasticsearch

Comment: Frankly, I'm put off by a structure like *current code -> external link -> The flaw is ...*. Why don't you first mention that what follows is an Elasticsearch query and post the code directly as block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your data might be better suited to being in one index, in which case you could use  and/or filters to combine a geo distance filter with a type filter.

Another option would be to use the [indicies](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/indices-query.html) query